# Fetching data from Cloud Firestore using StreamBuilder but always null

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my code:

```
body: StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("mydata").snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){

    if(!snapshot.hasData){return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);}

    return ListView(
      children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
        return InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => page2(faculityname: doc.id,)
          ));},
            child: customcard(   doc.id  ,   doc['image'] , 'this is description'));

      }).toList(),
    );
  },
),
```

I don't know what should I do I always get null and my data in Cloud Firestore is not null.

Comment: Also try checking `snapshot.hasError`, checking the ref path, and debug/printing data

Comment: Kindly add a screenshot of your firestore structure

Comment: I found that this happened to me when I add Google mlkit dependency just adding the dependency make this problem and when I remove the dependency it work fine